# installing wifi drivers on 2006 white imac

Tags: wireless, drivers, mac

I recently purchased an imac on ebay and installed ubuntu on it but ther is no wifi available.I ran the command to find out the wifi card and this is what i got.

```
michael@michael-iMac:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8053 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:4362] (rev 22)
    Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. Marvell RDK-8053 [11ab:5321]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4312] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:0089]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
michael@michael-iMac:~$
```

Could someone please provide me with with the terminal command to install the drivers to make wifi available on the mac. Thank you in advance.